# Fusion Starter Theme does not provide option to disable grid overlay for administrator on home page

Tags: theming

Enabling the option to display a grid overlay using a subtheme of Fusion Core under `Menu > Administration > Appearance > Settings` does what it is supposed to, however, does not give me the option (i.e. button) to turn the grid off on the home page. To turn the grid off, I have to go back into the Administrator Settings page of the subtheme and uncheck the option to enable the grid overlay for administrators. Also, I am unable to enable/disable the `Labels` tag that appears on the top or bottom right corner of the home page.

My configuration is as follows:

```
Drupal 7.30
Fusion Core 7.x-2.0-beta2
Fusion Core Starter subtheme (the .info and .css files of which I have renamed according to my own subtheme)
Fusion Accelerator 7.x-2.0-beta1
Chaos Tools 7.x-1.4
Localization Update 7.x-1.0
Advanced Help 7.x-1.1
Libraries 7.x-2.2
Localization Map 7.x-2.3
Skinr 7.x-2.0
Skinr UI 7.x-2.0
jQuery Update 7.x-2.4
Superfish 7.x-1.9
```

What is really baffling is that I have configured another Drupal site with almost the same themes and modules (except for jQuery, Superfish and Localization Update). I have no issues enabling/disabling the grid overlay nor the labels on the home page. The label to enable/disable the grid overlay for this site appears on the top right of the home page.

Comment: It seems that this problem is not new. It appears that the grid overlay button does not appear when using Skinr 2.x-dev release. See following link: https://www.drupal.org/node/837780. Note, however, that this issue was reported for Fusion 6.x-1.x-dev.

Comment: Further investigation has revealed that this may be a problem with the jQuery update, since disabling it resolves the problem. Unfortunately, it is also a dependency for the Superfish module....